# How to ignore an @ExceptionHandler from a dependency?

Tags: java, spring, exception, controller, exceptionhandler

I'm having a problem trying to return a "*ResponseEntity*" in one of my methods which is located in a custom exception handler (annotated with **@ExceptionHandler** and **@ControllerAdvice**), I'm calling this method from a "doOnError" (rxjava), but my problem is that when I do this not only my method is called, also another **@ExceptionHandler** in a **@ControllerAdvice** annotated class is called, but this class is not in my project, is in one of my dependencies.. so, to clarify my problem:

I'm trying to handle every exceptions in my project returning a ResponseEntity, but when I do this on my **@ExceptionHandler** inside my **@ControllerAdvice**, another one located in my dependencies is called after my custom one, so the response entity that I've build, is never returned, It just return the created by the dependency **@ExceptionHandler**.

My **question** is, there is a way to avoid the call to the dependency exception handler?

**Notes**:

- the **@ExceptionHandler** is being used for the method inside the
  exception handler class, this last one is annotated with
  **@ControllerAdvice.**
- I've tried with the Order and Priority annotations but they didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I tried with the `@ComponentScan`solution proposed by João and it didn't work for me because the exception handler located in my dependencies is not annotated as a component.. so I started to research again and I figured it out that when I add another parameter to the "handleException" method in my exception handler (which is annotated as `@ExceptionHandler`) it doesn't works, because I deleted the second parameter (I had only the "throwable") and it started to work! So in resume, I added the ..

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
```

..annotation to my exception handler class and put only one parameter (the exception) in the `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method, which will retrieve the *"ResponseEntity"* that I needed.

Comment: @OmidRostami have you tried the João answer approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent classes from being loaded using `@ComponentScan` from Spring (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#excludeFilters).

You can either create a custom exclusion filter for that specific `ExceptionHandler` class, define the packages you want to exclude (might not be feasible depending on the package where the handler is defined) or even define specific classes to exclude.

Comment: Do you know if is possible to add an "excludeFilters" in a @ComponentScan in order to exclude a external library package?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Try to create a custom filter `@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @Filter(type = CUSTOM, classes = ExcludingThirdPartyControllerAdvice.class))`. This filter class must implement `TypeFilter` and, assuming your 3rd party advice is being scanned, you can return `true` from the filter when the bean is loaded in order to prevent its execution.